# How to merge two different vocabulary in one auto-complete text-field?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have two taxonomies like below:

```
Content--- editor pick
       --- recommended
       --- today high
Sources--- sky
       --- earth
       --- water
```

to attach these with blog-post i need to make 2 different auto-complete text-box.
I want to make a single text box and both the taxonomy should be suggested in that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module. You can able to reference multiple vocabulary terms using this module.

See the screenshot of field settings of field type "Entity Reference" and Widget types "Auto-complete (Tags Style)"

[image]

Comment: great help! Doing so will affect my taxonomy/faceted search in anyway? Does entity reference module preserve all the taxonomies attachments?